# MIP SDK Getting Access Denied error while invoking profile AddEngineAsync

Tags: c#, microsoft-information-protection, mip-sdk

Im trying to set label using MIP SDK. However while executing AddEngineAsync, I am getting access denied error. I am able to get access token from AAD APP. Any help would be great.

Code:

```
var engine = Task.Run(async () => await profile.AddEngineAsync(engineSettings)).Result;
```

Error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.InformationProtection.Exceptions.AccessDeniedException: The service didn't accept the auth token. Challenge:['']
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.Action.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<<CreateFileEngine>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\wb561362\Mip_ServicePrincipalAuth\mip-sdk-dotnet-file-SPA\Action.cs:line 178
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.Action.CreateFileEngine(Identity identity) in C:\Users\wb561362\Mip_ServicePrincipalAuth\mip-sdk-dotnet-file-SPA\Action.cs:line 178
   at MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.Action..ctor(ApplicationInfo appInfo) in C:\Users\wb561362\Mip_ServicePrincipalAuth\mip-sdk-dotnet-file-SPA\Action.cs:line 113
   at MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Following is the access we have
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should validate you're getting a token for the correct resource. Typically, we see this error when people have hard coded or improperly handled the auth challenge in their auth delegate implementation.

Be sure that you're not hard coding the resource and that you're passing the resource provided as a parameter to AcquireToken() to your MSAL or ADAL implementation.

Comment: Thanks Tom I am not hard coding resource. May I know what are the base permissions required to read labels using MIP SDK? I'm not tenant admin or having any edit access on azure.

Comment: The API permissions are described here. You must have an application registered that has  UnifiedPolicy.User.Read.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/concept-api-permissions

Comment: Thanks Tom, it was native client redirect URI not configured correctly. Works now.

Comment: Thanks Tom. 'UnifiedPolicy.User.Read' is required if you are using delegated permissions. 'UnifiedPolicy.Tenant.Read' permission worked for me because I was using application permissions.